# Including Frontend CSS file into Backend in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to include a css file located in **frontend/web/css** to backend main layout.  It is **working for backend** but **produce error for frontend**. frontend web url is **staging.example.com** and backend web url is **backend.example.com**.

```
<?php
namespace frontend\assets;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class IconAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@frontend/web';
    public $css = [
        'css/icon.css',
    ];
}
?>
```

**Code inside frontend layout main.php**

```
use frontend\assets\IconAsset;
IconAsset::register($this);
```

**Code inside backend layout main.php**

```
use frontend\assets\IconAsset;
IconAsset::register($this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the Custom Asset Bundle in frontend as follows

```
     namespace frontend\assets;
     use yii\web\AssetBundle;
     use yii\web\YiiAsset;

        class CustomAsset extends AssetBundle{
            public $basePath = '@webroot';
            public $baseUrl = '@web';
            public $css = [
                'css/custom.css',
                'css/another_css.css'
            ];
        }`
```

Put above code in frontend web accessible folder and register this asset into bakend main layout file as follows

```
use frontend\assets\CustomAsset;
use Yii;

$bundle = CustomAsset::register(Yii::$app->view);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My code working for backend but give error when I try to register IconAsset in frontend main layout it gives error. Please tell me how to use this in frontend main layout.

Comment: refer this answer given by  [Carlos Manzo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154991/share-assets-between-frontend-and-backend-in-yii2-advanced-template)

Comment: I tried your code but got Cross origin request error since my fronted (staging.example.com) and backend (backend.example.com) have different subdomain